# Copy cell value based on checkbox and export into word

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA script that copies a cell value when a form control checkbox in the corresponding row is "checked". There are around 116 rows, and I only want to copy the cell value for the checked rows.

For example, my checkboxes are in cells D6:D122. If rows D6, D8, and D10 are checked, I want to copy the values within cells C6, C8, and C10, alphabetize the results and paste them into a newly generated Word document when a command button is clicked. I have figured out how to generate a new word document, but I have trouble copying over the cell values and alphabetizing them.

This is my code as of now:

```
Sub CommandButton1_click()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim var as Variant

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simpler solutions:

```
Sub CommandButton1_click()
    Dim cl As Range, txt As String
    
    For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D6:D122")
        If cl Then txt = txt & vbLf & cl.Offset(0, -1)
    Next cl
    
    If Len(txt) > 0 Then    ' show Word if you have something to output
        Dim wdApp As New Word.Application   ' declare and create object at once
        With wdApp
            .Documents.Add  ' the added document automatically becomes active
            .Selection.TypeText Mid(txt, 2)   'remove extra (lead) vbLf and output text to Word
            .ActiveDocument.Range.Sort
            .Visible = True 'show Word after processing to improve performance
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "There is nothing to output", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    End If
End Sub
```